# Date comparison in android

Tags: java, android

I'm facing some problems in comparing the current date and the date which is retrieved from Database.I just retrieved date from DataBase and Stored in a Date variable like this

```
String due_date_task = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dueDateOfTask));

SimpleDateFormat currentFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date1 = currentFormater.parse(due_date_task);
```

Now,what i want is should check whether date which is retrieved from DataBase is Equivalent to CurrentDate or not.

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date2 = currentDate.getTime();

if(date1.equals(date2))
```

System.out.println("Today Task");

i just want to check like this.Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to implement a Comparator, [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) compares if two objects are identical as in reference not in content

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
private boolean compareDates(Calendar objCal1, Calendar objCal2) {

  return ((objCal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == objCal2.get(Calendar.YEAR))
    && (objCal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == objCal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)));
}
```

creating the calendar objects:

```
Calendar objCal1 = new GregorianCalendar().setTime(date);
Calendar objCal2 = new GregorianCalendar().setTime(date1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For exact match including milliseconds, use **getTime**:

```
if(date.getTime() == date1.getTime()){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: This condition will be true for date1 = 4/4/2012 00:00:00 and date2 = 4/4/2012 00:00:00

Comment: date variable is from calender class i mean Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstace();Date date = currentDate.getTime(); and the other date obj is from DataBase That is date1 has dynamic values

Comment: if you create a new date (*date1* in your case) from SimpleDateFormat used for database date, then it would be good to do the comparison

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to get the current date,

```
Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.i("Time in mili of Current - Normal", ""+calCurr.getTimeInMillis()); // see what it gives? dont know why?
Date date = new Date();
calCurr.set(date.getYear()+1900, date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());// so added one month to it
Log.i("Time in mili of Current - after update", ""+calCurr.getTimeInMillis()); // now get correct
```

now create Calendar object for database value,

```
String due_date_task = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dueDateOfTask));      

SimpleDateFormat currentFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");      
Date date = currentFormater.parse(due_date_task);     
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());
```

and now Compare both the Calendar objects

```
if(calCurr.equals(start))
```

Comment: i have to compare due_date_task with current Date not with two different calenders calcur and start