# How to ensure that the date selected is the same in the database?

Tags: android, database, datepicker

I will insert DATE into the DATABASE, using a datepicker. It will be stored as STRING in the database. My another step is to check the date. By this, I mean I will have a edittext and a button. In the Edit Text, it will select the date using datapicker.

Upon clicking on the button, it will check whether the database have the date. If have, it will direct to another page, else it will toast no such date.

This is my code:

```
selection.java

public class selection extends Activity {


    Button newButton;
    Button updateButton;
    Button deleteButton;
    Button summaryButton;
    static EditText updateEdit;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection);

        updateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateEdit);


        updateEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                }
            });



        newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newBTN);
         newButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                 Intent mainAct=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(mainAct);

            }

            });












         updateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateBTN);
         updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                 Intent updateAct=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),update.class);
                 startActivity(updateAct);

            }

            });
















         deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteBTN);
         deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent updateAct=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),update.class);
                 startActivity(updateAct);

            }

            });

         summaryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.summaryBTN);
         summaryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent summaryView=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),summary.class);
                 startActivity(summaryView);

            }

            });



        }
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public EditText editText;
        DatePicker dpResult;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        updateEdit.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        // set selected date into datepicker also


    }
    }
}
```

DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter {



    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "fuelprice";
    public static final String KEY_FUEL = "fuelpump";
    public static final String KEY_COST = "tcost";
    public static final String KEY_ODM = "odometer";
    public static final String KEY_CON = "fcon";

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "fuelLog";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;



    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table fuelLog (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "date text not null, fuelprice text not null, fuelpump text not null, tcost text not null, odometer text not null, fcon text not null);";


        private final Context context;    

        private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx){
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context){
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
            {
                try{
                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }//onCreate

            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
                onCreate(db);
            }//onUpgrade

        }//DatabaseHelper


        public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }//open


        //---closes the database---    
        public void close() 
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }//close


        //---insert a log into the database---
        public long insertLog(String date, String fuelprice, String fuelpump,String tcost,String odometer,String fcon ) 
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, fuelprice);
            initialValues.put(KEY_FUEL, fuelpump);
            initialValues.put(KEY_COST, tcost);
            initialValues.put(KEY_ODM, odometer);
            initialValues.put(KEY_CON, fcon);


            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }//insertLog
        }
```

selection.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


   <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:stretchColumns="1 ">

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <Button
            android:id="@+id/newBTN"
            android:text="New"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px" >
        </Button>
       </TableRow>

         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/updateBTN"
            android:text="Update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px" >
        </Button>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/updateEdit" 
                android:text="" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:editable="false"
                android:enabled="true">
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteBTN"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px" >
        </Button>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/deleteEdit" 
                android:text="" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>


          <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/summaryBTN"
            android:text="Summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60px" >
        </Button>

        </TableRow>




        </TableLayout>





</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Get all your dates from your database and compare to the date you picked in a loop. Are the inserted dates the same in format as the ones you pick from date picker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date comparison in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008911/date-comparison-in-android)

Comment: @longwalker the date inserted in string..

Comment: @longwalker i not sure if I were to retrieve it out, what format should it be

Comment: @RohanKandwal it's kind of different

Comment: Can't you just just cast the datetime into a string and use a regular old query?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a method in your `DBAdapter` to get the dates into an array or arraylist e.g. `datesList`:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllDates() {
        ArrayList<String> datesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
                yourColumn, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToLast();
        while (!cursor.isBeforeFirst()) {

            // I am thinking your date is located at 1
            String date = cursor.getString(1);
            datesList.add(date);
            cursor.moveToPrevious();
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return datesList;
    }
```

And for comparing the dates, start a loop something like:

```
DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter();
adapter.open();
ArrayList <String> datesList = adapter.getAllDates();
for (String d:datesList){
        if (d.equals(date)){
            // do something

            return;
        }
    }
```

It is important that the pattern of dates from database and from date picker are important such as "dd/MM/yyyy". Hope it helps